# Make variables forget the previous values?

Tags: c++

I'm having a really irritating problem.

Firstly, I wrote a program that runs only for once and everything was perfect until I decided to make it re-executable with an user input.

Now I'm in a big trouble. When I re-execute the program, it falls into the wrong switch or if statements since the variables doesn't re-initialize themselves. To portray it:

```
// Libraries and other stuff

int numA, numB, numC;
char charA = 'A', charB = 'B', charC = 'C';

int main() {

do {

// Randomly assigning some numbers between 1-3 range into numA, numB and numC

...

// Converting the integers above into chars depending on the random numbers

switch (numA)
{
  case 1:
  numA = charA;
  break;

  case 2:
  numA = charB;
  break;

  case 3
  numA = charC;
  break;
}

switch (nu...

...

// A lot of IFs and SWITCHs that consistently changes the values above within themselves.

...

// Taking 1 input from user to re-execute the program

} while (input == 1)

return 0;

}
```

I know I messed everything up with not initializing the variables properly at first but I wasn't planing to make it re-executable when I started creating it, and now I'm looking for the optimal way to escape. Can I somehow make variables forget the previous values that they carry? Or do I really need to re-initialize everything from scratch?

Comment: How about you start by assigning their values to 0 when initializing them just to be safe since I don't know what your code does with them later. Also, if I understand, when they need to be reused again from start, assigning equal to 0. Could you post the code that assigns them numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move declaration of your variables into a scope inside the loop, so they will be reinitialized on each pass.

```
int main() {

do {
//new scope
{
int numA, numB, numC;
char charA = 'A', charB = 'B', charC = 'C';

// Randomly assigning some numbers between 1-3 range into numA, numB and numC

...

// Converting the integers above into chars depending on the random numbers

switch (numA)
{
  case 1:
  numA = charA;
  break;

  case 2:
  numA = charB;
  break;

  case 3
  numA = charC;
  break;
}

switch (nu...

...

// A lot of IFs and SWITCHs that consistently changes the values above within themselves.

...

// Taking 1 input from user to re-execute the program
}//end of scope
} while (input == 1)
```

However you should understand, that usage of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior and should always be avoided.

Also your char variables initialization (`char charA = 'charA'`) is completely invalid. You could not store 6 character string (5 characters and null terminator) in one character variable. You either should use `char*` or this is simple typographical error and it should be `char charA = 'A'`.

Comment: You just saved the day :) Thank you! (by the way, sorry for confusing. I mistakenly made the char initialization wrong up there, I edited it now.)

Answer (score 0):

You initialized all chars to 'c'. As you are initialising all chars to 'charA', 'charB' & 'charC' but while initialising chars it need only one character like `char ch1= '6', ch2='\n' ;`
As all the initializers have first letter common that is 'c'. That's why all initialized to 'c'.
Also you forgot the semicolon after *while*() of do.
Also you are using numA as switch control variable. & inside switch statement you are changing value inside numA. This is not wrong, but bad practice. Sorry for many edit, as I'm on stackexchange app I need to see question many times.